# Independency of random variable and sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, independence, means

Let:

- $F=({F_t})_{t>0}$  be a filtration of $\sigma$-algebras
- $C_t$ be an $F_{t-1}$-measurable r.v
- $\tilde{Y}_t$ be an $F_{t}$-measurable r.v.

It is sufficent to assume that $\tilde{Y}_t$ is independent on $F_{t-1}$ to state:

$E(C_t\cdot \tilde{Y}_t|F_{0})=E(C_t |F_{0})\cdot E(\tilde{Y}_t)$

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The definition of $\tilde{Y}$ is unclear, I suspect you are trying to define something that should not be defined. For example if X and Y are random variables there is no such thing as a new random variable $X|Y$ or $X|\{Y=1\}$.

Comment: I can say that the the unconditioned random variable $Y_t$ is deterministic $0$, if $I_t=0$ and the continuous random variable $\tilde{Y}_t$ if $I_t=1$

Comment: There is no such thing as a "conditioned random variable" or an "unconditioned random variable" so you should remove the fourth bullet. You can define $\tilde{Y}_t$ as a random variable and then define $Y_t = \tilde{Y}_tI_t$ if you like. You cannot derive the equation you state but you can say that if $C_t$ is $F_{t-1}$ measurable and if $I_t, \tilde{Y}_t$ are conditionally independent given $F_{t-1}$ then $$E[C_tI_t \tilde{Y}_t|F_0] = E[E[C_t I_t \tilde{Y}_t|F_{t-1}]|F_0] = E[C_t E[I_t|F_{t-1}]E[\tilde{Y}_t|F_{t-1}]|F_0]$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael. If i change my question as you can see above, this is correct? Thanks.

Comment: The first three bullets in the edit imply $$E[C_t\tilde{Y}_t|F_0] = E[C_tE[\tilde{Y}_t|F_{t-1}]|F_0]$$ But I do not know what "$\tilde{Y}_t$ is independent on $F_{t-1}$" means. If $E[\tilde{Y}_t|F_{t-1}]=E[\tilde{Y}_t]$ then indeed you can pull that constant out of the conditional expectation to get $E[\tilde{Y}_t]E[C_t|F_0]$.